# Sum of Parts of An Array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, reduce

Trying to solve [this challenge on codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/sums-of-parts/train/javascript). According to the challenge, the parts of array:

`ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`

Are

```
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]
ls = [3, 6, 10]
ls = [6, 10]
ls = [10]
ls = []
```

And we need to return an array with the sums of those parts.

So my code is as follows:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  let arrayOfSums = []; 
  while(ls.length > 0) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    arrayOfSums.push(sum);
    ls.shift();
  }
return arrayOfSums;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

The issue is that it wants us to add the last sum 0 when the array is empty. So we should be getting:

> [ 20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0 ]

Instead of

> [ 20, 20, 19, 16, 10]

So I tried this:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  let arrayOfSums = []; 
  while(ls.length > 0) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    arrayOfSums.push(sum);
    ls.shift();
  }
arrayOfSums.push(0);
return arrayOfSums;
}
console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

And this:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  ls.push(0);
  let arrayOfSums = []; 
  while(ls.length > 0) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    arrayOfSums.push(sum);
    ls.shift();
  }
return arrayOfSums;
}
```

But these caused execution time-out errors on Codewars:

> Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)

So I also tried:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  let arrayOfSums = []; 
  while(ls.length > -1) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    arrayOfSums.push(sum);
    ls.shift();
  }
return arrayOfSums;
}
```

But now this causes a TypeError:

> TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value

I am not understanding the concept of how to get 0 into the array when all of the values have been shifted out. The challenge seems to want 0 as the final "sum" of the array, even when the array is empty. But you cannot reduce an empty array - what else can I do here?

**EDIT**: Tried adding initial value to the reduce method:

```
function partsSums(ls) {
  let arrayOfSums = []; 
  while(ls.length > 0) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    arrayOfSums.push(sum);
    ls.shift();
  }
return arrayOfSums;
}
```

Unfortunately this still fails the basic test :

> expected [] to deeply equal [ 0 ]

Comment: I have tried to solve it myself. I don't know what else to try. I am not understanding the concept of how to add the sum of an empty array to the final array. Because you can't use reduce on an empty array. Any other ideas?

Comment: Cant you just push 0 after the loop?

Comment: You will notice that I tried that and it caused an execution time-out error.

Comment: This: _But you cannot reduce an empty array_ - that is not what that error message (_TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value_) says. In fact, it is very specific: Please re-read the documentation for reduce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Syntax - and then reread the error message.

Comment: @HappyHands31 it shouldnt cause a timeout error, because the while loop ends, and that code shouldn't take 12000ms to run.

Comment: @RandyCasburn "If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initialValue will throw a TypeError." So perhaps reduce is not the best method to find the sum of the array.

Comment: @Kobe It doesn't make sense that it causes an error, but on codewars, it does: https://www.codewars.com/kata/sums-of-parts/train/javascript

Comment: @RandyCasburn - ah, _initial_ value! I need to pass in an initial value, like:

`[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)` - I think.

Comment: One of the key use cases for reduce is summing the contents of an array. It is ideal for this purpose. What is the sum of an array of nothing? zero. But, you must also take into account that reduce is an iterator - you don't need two iterators.

Comment: BINGO! But consider the iterator point too.

Comment: Update while condition to while(ls.length > 0), as it will always be greater than -1, it goes to infinfite loop , and on shift, lenght is 0, push 0 to arrayofSums - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EBXNRX?editors=1010

Comment: @RandyCasburn Unfortunately adding 0 as the initial value still didn't work. Error is `expected [] to deeply equal [ 0 ]`. I do not quite understand what you mean by "you don't need two iterators". Would that mean that I wouldn't need the shift?

Comment: You are getting some great answers. Mark's is the most efficient and Nenad's is the least readable :-)

Comment: I guess the key thing is from the "Notes" section: *"Some lists can be long"*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no reason to compute the sum over and over. On a long array this will be very inefficient ( O(n²) ) and might explain your timeout errors. Compute the sum at the beginning and then subtract each element from it in a loop.

```js
ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]

function partsSums(ls) {
    let sum = ls.reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)
    res  = [sum]
    for (let i = 1; i <= ls.length; i++){
        sum -= ls[i-1]
        res.push(sum )
    }
    return res
}
console.log(partsSums(ls))
```

Comment: `O(n²)` means that the number of calculations required grows exponentially as the length of your array grows. The `reduce` needs to look at every element in the array and you do that *for* every element in the array.

Comment: @NinaScholz Are you talking about the initial `reduce()`? At least on chrome the overhead of the initial sum is much smaller than the penalty for `unshift()` in my tests.

Comment: So, to break this down a bit more, we have the first sum as `20`, then within the for-loop, we create the "result" array, initializing it to `20`.  Then we subtract `ls[i - 1]` from sum. So the first sum to get pushed into the result array from the for-loop will also be `20`, because `ls[i - 1]` in this case is `0`. Then 20 - 1, then 19 - 3, etc. Makes sense - thank you.

Comment: @HappyHands31 per Mark Meyer's comment above, if you need to ask "What is `( O(n^2))`" then you probably can benefit by being told explicitly this is called ["Big-O" notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that passed all of the tests:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
    let result = [0],
      l = ls.length - 1;
      
    for (let i = l; i >= 0; i--) {
        result.push(ls[i] + result[ l - i]);
    }
    return result.reverse();
}


console.log(partsSums([]));
console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10])); 
console.log(partsSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(partsSums([744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358]));
```

Comment: You could also do `result.unshift(ls[i] + result[0])` and avoid  `reverse`.

Comment: @georg `unshift` doesn't pass the test because it is slower than `push+reverse`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `for` loop with `slice` and when `i == 0` you can slice `len + 1` which is going to return you empty array and sum will be 0.

```js
function partsSums(arr) {
  const res = [], len = arr.length
  for (let i = len; i > -1; i--) {
    res.push(arr.slice(-i || len + 1).reduce((a, n) => a + n, 0))
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
console.log(partsSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(partsSums([744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358]));
```

You can also use two double `reduce` and if there is no next element push zero.

```js
function partsSums(arr) {
  const sum = arr => arr.reduce((r, e) => r + e, 0);
  return arr.reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    const res = sum(a.slice(i, a.length));
    return r.concat(!a[i + 1] ? [res, 0] : res)
  }, [])
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
console.log(partsSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(partsSums([744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate from the end and take this value plus the last inserted value of the result set.

This approach works with a single loop and without calculating the maximum sum in advance.

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  var result = [0],
      i = ls.length;
      
  while (i--) {
      result.unshift(ls[i] + result[0]);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
console.log(partsSums([]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With `push` and `reverse`.

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  var result = [0],
      l = 0,
      i = ls.length;
      
  while (i--) result.push(l += ls[i]);
  return result.reverse();
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
console.log(partsSums([]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this with recursion :

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  let sum = ls.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
  return  ls.length > 0 ? [sum].concat(partsSums(ls.slice(1))) : [0];
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
console.log(partsSums([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]));
console.log(partsSums([744125, 935, 407, 454, 430, 90, 144, 6710213, 889, 810, 2579358]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thing you could do

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
  if(!ls.length) return [0];
  let prevTotal = ls.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
  return [prevTotal, ...ls.map(val => prevTotal -= val)]
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Comment: I like this also - can you please help me understand how the `if(!ls.length) return [0]` gets added to the end of the returned array? There aren't any loops that are reducing the length of `ls`?

Comment: The `if(!ls.length) return [0]` is only used when the array passed in arguments is empty.
The reason it returns a 0 at the end, is because it's always substracting the value to the total, so when you get to the last value (10), you then substract it (10 - 10) so it returns 0!
For more info about the `map` method, you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).